# RSVP (Event management) for Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

What is the best way to implement RSVP system for SharePoint Online?

I was wondering if it's possible to implement a rsvp event manager system with modern tools (Microsoft Flow, SharePoint Online, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use SharePoint Online and MS Flow to design it as your requirement.

Comment: Is there any template where I can re use it?

Comment: there is no existing templates about it, you need to design it from blank based on your requirement.